# What is the `rewrite_rules` option the options table in the WordPress database?

Tags: rewrite-rules

I'm troubleshooting an issue with permalinks. As part of my troubleshooting, I discovered that this row in the table `wp_options` is changing:

```
+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------+
| option_id | option_name   | option_value   | autoload |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------+
|   1725617 | rewrite_rules | a:323:{...}    | yes      |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------+
```

(I put `...` in the value of the third field for brevity.)

What does the `rewrite_rules` option do? When is it used? How is it modified? What could modify it? Is there any documentation for this option? I haven't found documentation for it, yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found some documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/). It looks like this is accessed when saving the permalink settings under Settings->Permalinks. It looks like this works in conjunction with the rules stored in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

In WP Platform , the `rewrite_rules` option in the database perform important role in handling permalink structures and generating rewrite rules for WP URLs

`rewrite_rules` option stores an array of rewrite rules used by WordPress to parse incoming requests and determine what action to take based on the URL structure.

plugins and themes can also modify rewrite rules programmatically using functions like `add_rewrite_rule()` and `flush_rewrite_rules()`

> Changing the permalink structure in WordPress settings.
>
> Activating, deactivating, or updating plugins/themes that register
> custom rewrite rules.
>
> Programmatically adding or removing rewrite rules in plugin or theme
> code